# When building a simple ORM for a hierarchy of POCO objects based on a database, who should 'own' the data?

Tags: c#, database, collections, orm, poco

I've been struggling with a design of my data-driven app for some time right now and keep going back and forth on my implementation, causing a lot of wheel-spin without much actual movement.  Here's my problem.

I have a self-referencing table in my database representing a hierarchy of categories. They can recurse infinitely.  The root categories have no parent and each category, root or otherwise, can have zero or more subcategories.

If this were a pure POCO-based design without the database backing, I would just do this...

```
public class CategoryCollection : ObservableCollection<Category>
{
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CategoryCollection Subcategories = new CategoryCollection()
}

public CategoryCollection RootCategories = new CategoryCollection()
```

Then I'd stuff the RootCategories with the root instances and build out the hierarchy from there.

I may even extend it to have a parent so I can traverse up and down the hierarchy as needed.

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category? ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public CategoryCollection Subcategories = new CategoryCollection()
}
```

However, here's where things start to get confusing.  Who is responsible for ensuring the parent is in-sync with the collection? Who 'owns' that value? For instance, a new instance that hasn't yet been inserted into the RootCategories collection would also have 'null' for its parent, but it's not a root category until it's actually added.

You could invert this and *only* have a parent, but then you would have to do LINQ statements or similar to query who the subcategories are for any given parent.

Instead of a parent, I've also considered having an OwningCollection, then having the OwningCollection have a parent, like so...

```
public class CategoryCollection : ObservableCollection<Category>
{
    public Category? ParentCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CategoryCollection? OwningCollection{ get; set }
    public CategoryCollection Subcategories = new CategoryCollection()
}
```

While this addresses the Root Category issue (it's not part of the hierarchy if OwningCollection is null) this moves ownership of the parent to the collection, not the child, which kind of makes things cleaner as if you remove it from the collection, you've essentially removed its parent, but this doesn't stop someone from adding the category to multiple collections meaning multiple parents!  So that won't work and led me back to the Parent being the gospel.

Going down that road, I made the actual setter of the Parent property take care of adding and removing membership of the child collections which seemed like the right approach there.

But now throw in a database for storage and even that falls apart.

The table in the database is obviously the 'gospel' of the data, and as such, the model should always follow what the database says. As such, you can't simply set the parent like you could above, as then either the model needs to update the database, or someone listening to the model does, and depending on whether or not that db call succeeds or fails, then you need to update collection membership.

Ok, so how about removing the collections from the model and instead make them simple POCOs which are sent and received from the DAL/Storage layer via services.  Now the POCOs match the database directly.  Add simple caching and you can guarantee a single instance per ID.

```
var categoryCache = new CategoryCache()

public class Category
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category? ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Requests to the DAL now simply returned either a Category or an IEnumerable like so...

```
var category      = DAL.GetCategoryWithId(123)            // Returns Category
var subcategories = DAL.GetSubcategoriesWithParentId(123) // Returns IEnumerable<Category>
```

Internally, they both return row(s) from the database and either update existing instances in the cache (weakly stored), or added new ones to the cache ensuring fresh data whenever it's requested.

But this now breaks down when you actually need to show the hierchy updating in the UI because there's no longer any owning observable collections!  If something gets deleted from the database, and thus the cache, the UI can still be hanging on to that instance in a TreeView or a list on screen, and the model can't know every place that item is used.

So it's back to implementing the collections in the POCOs, and you're right back to the problem of who's responsibility is it to update those collections?  Do you allow inserting and removal directly, or do you perform all actions via service calls and they alone can update parents and collections?

OR...

Is the database *not* the gospel of the data, but rather what's in memory is the gospel, and the database shouldn't do anything except store things by ID. It means you'd have to remove constraints and such in the DB (such as ensuring names are unique at each level, etc.) and enforce that in the model level, but that doesn't stop someone from changing the data out from underneath you, meaning you now have to re-sync memory with the DB or vice-versa.

That's why I'm leaning more towards the 'Services are gospel' approach and everything on the model is otherwise read-only to all on the outside.

Even so, I'd still love to hear the community's thoughts on how I can improve this design.

Comment: Instead of modeling the problem domain in OOP (which supports only binary relationships and has no data integrity or manipulation features), I model the solution system in OOP (as in services that know of/talk about the domain). Knowledge of categories would be encapsulated state in objects like CategorizedReport or ProductCategorizationScreen or CategoryManager. My objects aren't data, they use data, and can talk to the DBMS directly without an ORM.

Comment: Can you give simple examples, and put it in an answer here?